# T-Sql. CTE and IN clause. Conversion failed

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, common-table-expression

Assume we have next t-SQL code:

```
;WITH [CTE] AS
(
    SELECT 0 [A], 'FAULT' [B]
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 1 [A], '1' [B]
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 2 [A], '2' [B]
),
[CTE2] AS
(
    SELECT [B]
    FROM [CTE]
    WHERE [A] > 0
)
SELECT * FROM [CTE2]
WHERE 1 IN (SELECT [B] FROM [CTE2])
```

This code faults with an error:

> "Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'FAULT' to data type int."

CTE just prepares data.
CTE2 filters data, so It should return two records, where [B] = '1' and [B] = '2'.
And then CTE2 is used in the IN clause.
1 is an Integer. So results of (SELECT [Value] FROM [CTE2]) must be converted to Integer.

Why does it try to convert string 'FAULT' to Integer? CTE2 does not return this string.

Comment: Because of your where clause. You have a 1 IN ... This means that it will attempt to implicitly convert the values in the subquery to the same datatype. What would you expect it do?

Comment: If you were to enclose the `1` in single quotes `'1'` then this would return what you want.

Comment: The query optimizer does curious things. While you think you have written steps that you want performed in a specific order, the optimizer sees a starting point. It can combine queries to optimize the performance of the query taken as a whole. Have a look at the execution plan to get a better idea of what is being done under the covers. Aside: According to the rules for [data type precedence](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/data-type-precedence-transact-sql), an `Int` (`1`) trumps a `VarChar` (`'1'`), forcing conversion of the string to a numeric value.

Comment: [SQL Server should not raise illogical errors](https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/537419/sql-server-should-not-raise-illogical-errors) - you can vote on it; but that issue has been open since 2010 with no real sign that it'll ever get resolved.

Answer (score 0):

What about:

```
;WITH [CTE] AS
(
    SELECT 0 [A], 'FAULT' [B]
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 1 [A], '1' [B]
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 2 [A], '2' [B]
)
SELECT * FROM [CTE]
WHERE [A] > 0
AND [B] = '1'
```

Output

```
A   B
1   1
```

SQL Fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/9eecb7db59d16c80417c72d1e1f4fbf1/7630/0

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like that:

```
WITH [CTE] AS
(
SELECT 0 [A], 'FAULT' [B]
UNION ALL
SELECT 1 [A], '1' [B]
UNION ALL
SELECT 2 [A], '2' [B]
),
[CTE2] AS
(
SELECT [B]
FROM [CTE]
WHERE [A] > '0'
)
SELECT * FROM [CTE2]
WHERE 1 IN (SELECT [B] FROM [CTE2] WHERE CASE WHEN ISNUMERIC([B]) = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END = 1)
```

Comment: `ISNUMERIC` is the function that answers a question that nobody wants to ask - "can this string be converted to *any* of the numeric data types (I don't care which ones it can be converted to)?". I.e. your filter would let through `1d1` which also cannot be converted to `int`.

Answer (score 0):

This is matter of [type precedence](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/data-type-precedence-transact-sql):

> When an operator combines two expressions of different data types, the rules for data type precedence specify that the data type with the lower precedence is converted to the data type with the higher precedence.
>
> 16.int
>
> 27.varchar

So int "wins". But `FAULT` is not valid int value. You could use explicit cast:

```
;WITH [CTE] AS
(
    SELECT 0 [A], 'FAULT' [B]
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 1 [A], '1' [B]
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 2 [A], '2' [B]
),
[CTE2] AS
(
    SELECT [B]
    FROM [CTE]
    WHERE [A] > 0
)
SELECT * FROM [CTE2]
WHERE CAST(1 AS VARCHAR(10)) IN (SELECT [B] FROM [CTE2]);
```

**[Rextester Demo](http://rextester.com/JEL51106)**

---

Please note that construct:

```
SELECT * FROM [CTE2]
WHERE 1 IN (SELECT [B] FROM [CTE2])
```

will return all rows if `[B]` is not null and `1` is in set.